# whats wrong with this while loop in unix

Tags: shell, unix, sum-of-digits

I am a newbie .Please help me with this

The output says syntax error near unexpected token 'do'

The code is

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ];
then 
echo "Command line arguments are missing."
else
n=$1
sum=0
while[ $n -gt 0 ]
do
   rem=$(( $n % 10 ))
   sum=$(( $sum + $rem ))
   n=$(( $n / 10 ))
done 
echo "Sum of digit for given number is $sum "
fi
```

Comment: If you are a newbie, stop using `[`.  At the very least, just replace it with the equivalent, but far more readable `test`.  `if test $# -eq 0; ..` and `while test $n -gt 0; ...`.  It becomes immediately clear why `whiletest $n...` is an error.

Answer (score 0):

A whitespace after `while`. Try this out:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ];
then
  echo Command line arguments are missing.
else
  n=$1
  sum=0
  while [ $n -gt 0 ];
  do
     rem=$(( $n % 10 ))
     sum=$(( $sum + $rem ))
     n=$(( $n / 10 ))
  done
  echo "Sum of digit for given number is  $sum"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Put spaces before and after `[` and `]`.
You can replace the while-loop with

```
sum=$(( $(echo $1| sed 's/./&+/g; s/+$//' ) ))
```